# Angular 12: Can I handle multiple types of responses from an API using HttpClient?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, httpclient, fetch-api

I have this code below and as you can see, it just checks if my response from API is OK and returns a value or throws an error that I can catch.

```js
fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/test`, {
   method: "post",
   body: JSON.stringify({ "data": my_payload })
})
.then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }

  throw response;
})
.then(data => data)
.catch(err => err);
```

I simply tried to start to use the HTTPClient to send the same request for the API, as you can see in the code below:

```js
this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/api/test',
{ "data": my_payload })
.pipe(
  catchError(err => throwError(() => err))
);
```

**The problem is that the API responds with a JSON when all the process runs fine but when an error occurs, the API throws an error with plain text describing why the error occurred.**

So I received this log on my console:

> TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable.

Even when I tried to add the attribute `responseType: "text"` the error persists:

```js
this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/api/test',
{ "data": my_payload }, { responseType: "text" })
.pipe(
  catchError(err => throwError(() => err))
);
```

I really don't know how to handle this situation. I've tried to search for some answers and basically, I found that the error could be in the `responseType` or the error could be in the version of the `RXJS` that, by the way, is in the **7.5.0** or even others solutions involving to make an `interceptors class` but, in my situation, it only change the place where the error occurs.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator of rxjs to validate the response and throw an error manually, using `throw new Error(<<error message>>)`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'zone.js';
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { catchError, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const my_payload = {};
    this.http
      .post<any>('https://user1706273767308.requestly.tech/test?', {
        data: my_payload,
      })
      .pipe(
        catchError((err: any) => throwError(() => new Error(err)))
      )
      .subscribe(<any>{
        next: (res: any) => {
          console.log('next', res);
        },
        error: (res: Error) => {
          console.log('error', res);
        },
        complete: (res: any) => {
          console.log('complete', res);
        },
      });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8xazsu?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Wow you answered 200+ Angular questions in the last 30 days and are on top of the table. Kudos!

Comment: @YongShun Thank you! Wishing you all the best, Your answers are always clear and concise, great work!

Comment: @NarenMurali Thank you for your help! In your example, the API always returns an HTTP status 2xx but the "status" property is "false". In my case, the API returns an HTTP status 4xx, so "map" doesn't trigger but "catchError" does. I made a few changes to your project to see if I got the same error that occurred in my project and your project works well! Your Angular version is 17.1.1 and mine is 12.1.1, and your RXJS is 7.8.1 and mine is 7.5.0. It looks like I have a version problem here!